# Correct data format for ngfor

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I control the api endpoint so I can format the json I receive in the best way required so i don't have to manipulate the json too much. I have this chunk of data stored in a variable as an object:

```
mediagrupo= [{
    "2019-06": [{
        "id_formulario": "4",
        "media": "7.6800"
    }],
    "2019-05": [{
        "id_formulario": "1",
        "media": "7.2031"
    }, {
        "id_formulario": "2",
        "media": "8.0459"
    }, {
        "id_formulario": "3",
        "media": "7.7752"
    }, {
        "id_formulario": "4",
        "media": "8.4800"
    }],
    "2019-04": [{
        "id_formulario": "2",
        "media": "6.0000"
    }]
}]
```

What I want is something like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of mediagrupo">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let form of item">
        <td>{{ form["media"] }}</td>
    </ng-container>
</tr>
```

But Either I get an error that it's not the correct type, its undefined... What would the correct structure of the json would be to get something like this working?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert an object built of key-value pairs to an array with the `keyvalue` pipe.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of mediagrupo">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let form of (item | keyvalue)">
        <td>{{ form.key }}</td>
        <td>{{ form.value }}</td>
...
```

https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe

Comment: I see key value is a pipe of angular 6 and I'm using 5.2 Im afraid to update it and break something else

Comment: I could change and maybe even duplicate the info inside, not very elegant but including the date inside again will give me access to it

Comment: It'll be easy to implement the pipe manually. Actually, you can just copy-paste its source from Angular, it doesn't seem to have any non-trivial dependencies, except some type definitions.

Answer (score 2):

Your Json object is correct, but you are not binding the object correctly. As your variable "item" `(*ngFor="let item of mediagrupo")` ***is a key-value pair and not an array or object***, So you can't loop through it again. First, you will have to get the value of a particular "item" then only it will work.

This line is causing a problem in your case -
        `<td>{{ form["media"] }}</td>`

you could do something like -

```
<tr  *ngFor="let month of mediaGroup">
    <td *ngFor="let m of month['2019-06']"> // here I am refering to paricular key-value
       {{m.media}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Hope this helps. However, I have changed the variables name.

Again, You could modify the array of json something like -

```
 [
  {
    "month": "2019-05",
    "medias": [
      {
        "id_formulario": "1",
        "media": "7.2031"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "month": "2019-06",
    "medias": [
      {
        "id_formulario": "1",
        "media": "7.2031"
      },
      {
        "id_formulario": "2",
        "media": "8.0459"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Traversing would be easier like this.

Comment: I think I'll have to duplicate info in the json, not very elegant but including the date inside again will give me access to it.

Comment: You could modify the array of json like - 

```
 [
  {
    "month": "2019-05",
    "medias": [
      {
        "id_formulario": "1",
        "media": "7.2031"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "month": "2019-06",
    "medias": [
      {
        "id_formulario": "1",
        "media": "7.2031"
      },
      {
        "id_formulario": "2",
        "media": "8.0459"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```
Traversing would be easy like this.

Comment: I like this. Might end up doing it this way

Comment: @monxas, I am glad that the provided solution helped you.  If you really liked the solution, you could accept the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The second *ngFor is causing the problem, `item` is an object (a row of the array of objects `mediagrupo`), not an array, you can't iterate over it, and you don't need to (at least from what I can see)

Comment: I still need to get access to the key (the "2019-06" values)

Answer (score 1):

After seeing what you desire from other answers, you can do the following without using the keyvalue pipe:
Add this function to your TS:

```
getKeys(item: any){
  return Object.keys(item);
}
```

This returns an array containing all the keys inside an object, we'll use these keys to do the rest, in our HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of mediagrupo">
    <p *ngFor="let key of getKeys(item)">
      {{key}}
      <span *ngFor="let child of item[key]">
        {{child.media}}
      </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

I used div and p for the sake of simplicity, change them to tr and td, **[here's a stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dwc58h?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**.

Comment: Well this is perfect

Comment: Great! If it solved your problem mark it as solution